# How to convert dynamic scriptlets to JSP 2.0 with JSTL/EL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, scriptlet

I need to grab a dynamically-named variable off of the request. This works in scriptlet form, but I'd rather not clutter up the page with scriptlets.

```
<%
    String requestValueKey = "something_" + request.getParameter("State") + "_" + request.getParameter("UUID");    
    String requestValue = request.getParameter(requestValueKey);
%>
```

I'd like to switch it to JSTL but I can't figure out how to come up with a dynamically named session value key that relies on other values in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<c:set>` to prepare the dynamic key and use brace notation `[]` to get a value by a dynamic key.

```
<c:set var="requestValueKey" value="something_${param.State}_${param.UUID}" />
```

Then you can get it by `${param[requestValueKey]}` in remnant of the page.

Comment: Thank you. Technically, my answer remains the same.